# Cannot connect to SQL instance

Tags: sql, connection

Hello I'm having serious trouble connecting to a SQL instance that I was connecting to fine just yesterday.

I checked the log file and saw this-
"Could not connect because the maximum number of '1' user connections has already been reached. The system administrator can use sp_configure to increase the maximum value. The connection has been closed."

I was able to connect to the Database Engine Query and changed the maximum value to 0, however I am still unable to connect.

Next I ran this query to see all open connections

SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
    COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
    loginame as LoginName
FROM
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
    dbid > 0
GROUP BY 
    dbid, loginame

and it told me that there were 16 connections to the master database. How can I close all of these connections? I can not stop or restart the instance either. When I try to the progress bar just disappears and I get no error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to resolve your issue is in this link on MSDN..

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2015/07/21/error-while-connecting-to-sql-server-could-not-connect-because-the-maximum-number-of-1-user-connections-has-already-been-reached/